# Apple Error LLVM 3.1

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm really scared about this, I was coding today and I tried to change the name of the app in the build settings.. Now I get this error and I don't know what to do... the error came after changing the name, so I returned how it was but still getting the error.

Any ideas?

```
ProcessPCH /Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-    dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CogniviaTaxi2012-cnqijsqktrplrbdjpydsurpnfjtl/CogniviaTaxi2012.pth CogniviaTaxi2012 normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
cd /Users/Tidane/Desktop/CogniviaTaxi2012
setenv LANG en_US.US-ASCII
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c-header -arch i386 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -fobjc-arc -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wmissing-prototypes -Wreturn-type -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wno-undeclared-selector -Wno-deprecated-implementations -DDEBUG=1 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -fexceptions -fasm-blocks -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -Wno-conversion -Wno-sign-conversion -fobjc-abi-version=2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch "-DIBOutlet=__attribute__((iboutlet))" "-DIBOutletCollection(ClassName)=__attribute__((iboutletcollection(ClassName)))" "-DIBAction=void)__attribute__((ibaction)" -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -iquote /Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/CogniviaTaxi2012-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/CogniviaTaxi2012-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/CogniviaTaxi2012-all-target-headers.hmap -iquote /Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/CogniviaTaxi2012-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -I/Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/DerivedSources/i386 -I/Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CogniviaTaxi2012.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator --serialize-diagnostics /Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CogniviaTaxi2012-cnqijsqktrplrbdjpydsurpnfjtl/CogniviaTaxi2012.dia -c 
/Users/Tidane/Desktop/CogniviaTaxi2012/CogniviaTaxi2012 -o /Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CogniviaTaxi2012-cnqijsqktrplrbdjpydsurpnfjtl/CogniviaTaxi2012.pth -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/Tidane/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CogniviaTaxi2012-dibsqcvprykadbdonevlhydjtyef/Build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders/CogniviaTaxi2012-cnqijsqktrplrbdjpydsurpnfjtl/CogniviaTaxi2012.d

error: error reading '/Users/Tidane/Desktop/CogniviaTaxi2012/CogniviaTaxi2012'
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Please, please, ***please*** format your errors as code.

Comment: Change the name back and what happens?

Comment: It get still the same error... I was testing good and then got this

Comment: What happens if you make a new project and migrate everything over there?

Comment: I will do that I think... But it is a loooong project :(

Comment: Yes, it's annoying, I know, but if it fixes it, then it's worth it's weight in gold.  The compiler is not your friend right now.

Comment: Thank you very much... I'm pasting the code in a backup from yesterday.

Comment: No, no.  Don't even paste, just drag the files into the new project and make sure the "copy files..." box is checked.

Comment: App is now revived.. Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

I think I encountered the same problem.
I changed my app name, and suddenly I could not build the project.

In my case, I found "Prefix Header" of "Apple LLVM compiler 3.2 - Language" was changed to directory name, not file name.

So I manually fix it to XXXX-Prefix.pch, and now I can build the project.

I don't know my case is same as yours, but just for your info.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I managed to build again and app is now ready to download. thanks :)